# Spark SQL QUERY join on Same column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a join query for 2 dataframes. I have to perform join on column which has same name in both dataframes. How can I write it in Query?

```
var df1 = Seq((1,"har"),(2,"ron"),(3,"fred")).toDF("ID", "NAME")
var df2 = Seq(("har", "HARRY"),("ron", "RONALD")).toDF("NAME", "ACTUALNAME")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")
```

I know we can do `df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("NAME"))` where `NAME` is the common column. In this scenario `df3` will have only `ID, NAME, ACTUALNAME`.

If we do it from SQL then query will be `select * from table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME`. For this output dataframe will have `ID, NAME, NAME, ACTUALNAME` columns. How can I remove extra `NAME` column which came from `df2`.

This does not work as well `spark.sql("select * from table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME").drop(df2("NAME"))`

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Renaming `df2` columns is the last option which I don't want to use. I have scenario where creating SQL queries is easier than dataframes so looking for **only SPARK SQL Specific answers**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this you can use col() for referring column

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME").drop(col("table2.NAME")).show()
+---+----+----------+
| ID|NAME|ACTUALNAME|
+---+----+----------+
|  1| har|     HARRY|
|  2| ron|    RONALD|
|  3|fred|      null|
+---+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an academic exercise, but you can also do it without the need to drop columns by switching on the ability of Spark SQL to interpret regular expressions in quoted identifiers, an ability inherited from Hive SQL. You need to set `spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames` to `true` when building the Spark context for this to work.

```
$ spark-shell --master "local[*]" --conf spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true
...
scala> spark.sql("select table1.*, table2.`^(?!NAME$).*$` from table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME").show()
+---+----+----------+
| ID|NAME|ACTUALNAME|
+---+----+----------+
|  1| har|     HARRY|
|  2| ron|    RONALD|
|  3|fred|      null|
+---+----+----------+
```

Here

```
table2.`^(?!NAME$).*$`
```

resolves to all columns of `table2` except `NAME`. Any valid Java regular expression should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not apply an alias to the dataframe, you’ll receive an error after you create your joined dataframe. With two columns named the same thing, referencing one of the duplicate named columns returns an error that essentially says it doesn’t know which one you selected (Ambiguous). In SQL Server and other languages, the SQL engine wouldn’t let that query go through or it would automatically append a prefix or suffix to that field name.

Comment: Spark SQL internally prefixes each output column with the table name, it is just not visible. Selecting with a qualified column name works, e.g., `select(col("table1.NAME"))`.

Answer (score 0):

we can select the required fields in the sql query like below one

```
spark.sql("select A.ID,A.NAME,B.ACTUALNAME from table1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 B ON table1.NAME = table2.NAME").show()
```

Comment: Selection will work but as I mentioned in question it will be last priority. Original dataframe will have 750+ columns so cannot write such big query.